# UIScrollView : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview

found error on my UIScrollView, when i add userDefault to my AppDelegate

this is my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions on`AppDelegate`:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let is_authen = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "is_authen") // return false if not found
    if is_authen {
        //user logged in
        let home = homeViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = home //change root to homeViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 152/255, blue: 222/255, alpha: 1)
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
    return true
}
```

the `loginViewController` code:

```
class loginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var textFieldUsername: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldPassword: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.textFieldUsername.delegate = self
    self.textFieldPassword.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//hide keyboard
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

@IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let username = self.textFieldUsername.text!
    let password = self.textFieldPassword.text!

    let postString = ["username": username, "password": password]
    var request = URLRequest(url:URL(string:"http://iseoo.id/rest_ci_iseoo/login")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("application-idValue", forHTTPHeaderField: "secret-key")
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options:.prettyPrinted)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    //Post
    session.dataTask(with: request){data, response, err in
        //Guard: ws there error ?
        guard(err == nil) else {
            print("\(err)")
            return
        }
        //Guard: check was any data returned?
        guard let data = data else{
            print("no data return")
            return
        }
        //Convert Json to Object
        let parseResult: [String:AnyObject]!
        do{
            parseResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
            print("\(parseResult)")
        } catch {
            print("Could not parse data as Json \(data)")
            return
        }
        //Check jsonDictionary
        guard let jsonArray = parseResult["success"] as? [String:AnyObject]
            else{
                do {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginToTabBar", sender: self)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print ("jsonDictionary error")
                }
            return
        }
        //check jsonArray and switch to next ViewController
        if(jsonArray.count == 0 ){
            print("jsonArray not found")
            return
        } else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                print(jsonArray)
            }
        }

        //authentication text field

        }.resume()

    // save  logged state
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "is_authen")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

//presses return key
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return (true)
}
```

the `homeViewController` code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!

var imageArray = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "adidas"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "nike"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "sennheiser_logo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "telkom")]

    for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)

        mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i+1)
        mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

note: i try to delete ScrollView, but my app will blank after launchScreen. my ScrollView runs normally before i add UserDefaults

The error:
[image: sorry i still not allowed to embed image]

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: You only add a `rootViewController` when `is_authen` is true but you don't add anything when it's false.. maybe that causes your issue.

Comment: the error on my update @luk2302

Comment: The error message in the image reveals that `mainScrollView` is `nil`. Calling the default initializer `homeViewController()` does **not** return the instance in the storyboard. It creates a new instance without connected outlets. You have to *instantiate* the controller from the storyboard.

Comment: `let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "authenActive") as! homeViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`
i add this on the new root viewController after logged in, but now the error on the line `let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "authenActive") as! homeViewController` @vadian

Comment: Is the outlet connected at all in IB?

Comment: done. wait, where I must to add the instantiate?